# Is CentOS the most barebones Linux?

Tags: centos, filesystems, nas

I'm looking to make a NTFS filesystem NAS server with Docker support, so I need the most lightweight and feature-lacking OS, since I'll only use it to access the files on the system and run docker containers with whatever software I need, and, therefore, don't need anything from the OS, really, like the ability to play music, videos, etc.

Would CentOS suit me in this regard?

Comment: why don't you try it and decide for yourself ... you are the only person that can determine if something suits you

Answer (score 1):

Most distributions have some kind of "minimal installation" option with only the most basic set of tools needed to run the system. CentOS boot ISO is only 680 MB and allows minimal selection, similarly Debian has a netinst ISO and its installer also allows basic/minimal installation. You can also try some specialized NAS distributions or BSD based [FreeNAS](https://www.freenas.org/) if you want something minimal for a NAS system.